# EJB Timer: How to Start and stop EJB timer from client side?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, ejb, ejb-3.0

I am using J2EE to write a web application. Some where in my application I needed to have a timer, so I decided to use *EJB* timer on my server side. But the problem is at moment, when I started the server the timer automatically starts to work, But I have to be able to stop and start timer from client side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to add remote interface methods on the EJB that manually cancel and recreate the EJB timer.  There is no standard EJB API for stopping/restarting EJB timers, and there is no standard client API for even cancelling/creating timers

Comment: Thank you so much for your explanation.